# TextView is not showing č character

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am working on an android app in which I am getting data in multiple languages everything is working fine but i am facing a small problem some characters are not visible in **textview** and **edittext**

The main problem with this **č** character.

I tried some stuffs like:

```
Html.fromHtml("č");
```

I also tried unicode character format but still not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the font you're using define it?  Not all fonts know all characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the website show signs like "č" and "ć"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219271/how-to-make-the-website-show-signs-like-%c4%8d-and-%c4%87)

Comment: I am using Nexa Bold font in my app.

Comment: visit this question you will get your answer [How to make the website show signs like “č” and “ć”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219271/how-to-make-the-website-show-signs-like-%C4%8D-and-%C4%87)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML equivalent:

```
Html.fromHtml("&#269");
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#268");//Capital C-hachek

txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#269");//Lowercase c-hachek
```

see link:-

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cz.htm